# Initialize a UIView in high resolution for iPhone 4

Tags: iphone, uiview, resolution

How can i init a uiview to be in high resolution (640x960) on iphone4?
i tried to put a scaleFactor of 2.0 to the uiview but that did nothing
also how can i test that the device the app is running on accept high resolution  ie. it is an iphone 4

thanks in advance, Benoit

Answer (score 0):

It's already done when you launch your app on a iPhone 4.

If you need better image resolution, you need to adjust the size and rename it with @2x at the end.

What are you trying to do ?

Vincent

Comment: Hello Vincent,Thanks for your help. i try to initalize an UIView for a ViewController for a game. On iphone4, the view is initalized in 320*480. I dont have a xib to rename @2x at the end. i would like to dinamically instantiate the uiview in high resolution if the the app run on iphone4. It is for a game

Comment: If the app runs on iPhone 4, Apple will check if the retina image exists directly. For example, if you have [ UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png" ];, if image@2x.png exists, it will be used. Else, image.png will be ^^. But ... with what are you coding your games ? without big library ? openGL ?

Comment: Vinzius - a related question not worthy of it's own post - does this mean in xcode4/ib the size of a UIView will only ever be 320x480 & it gets rescaled on iphone4? ie each of the 320 x 480 points gets mapped to whatever number of pixels the native resolution the device has? and then when you display a graphic (say in uiimageview), it uses the appropriate version, assuming you give correct filename etc?

Comment: Hi. Yes. on iPhone the view frame will be 320*480, even with IB. If the user use a retina display, it'll take in priority the @2x (or else the normal one).